# how to use ssh to visit vm in openstack environment

Tags: linux, cloud, openstack

What I want to do: use python script to login the vm in openstack
    environment

What I did so far: I used CLI: `openstack keypair create
    abc > /root/keydir/abc` to create openstack keypair and use `chmod 600 abc to change the permission`

Then I create a vm from dashboard and use the key which I created just now

I set up the vm and wait it to the right state At last I use this command in controller node: ip netns exec qdhcp-c8db7805-c5e8-aaaa-xxxx-xxxxx ssh -i   /root/keydir/abc root@192.168.111.104(vm's ip) "ping 127.0.0.1 -c 10
    "

When I run this in python, it shows me: `Permission denied   (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).` I run the command in Linux directly it prompt me to input password, and this not the  result I want

Why doesn't the keypair work?

Comment: After generating a new SSH keypair the public key needs to be added to the authorized_keys file  in the home directory of the remote user  (i.e. to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`)  before the associated private key will be granted access. Also ssh access for the "root" account is blocked by default on many Linux distributions

Comment: I have set the PermitRootLogin in the /etc/sshd/sshd_config in the vm's os file before

Comment: By the way,when I boot a vm from nova,Dose not the openstack will help me to finish the pub/pem key things?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem I faced. When you generate the keys on the server side, you must export the RSA private/public key to the machine which you'd like to connect from. The public key (that's also in authorized keys) is the only one you'll need.

I use PuTTy to do this, because you can generate a .ppk file with the RSA key from Notepad. You just need to cat the file with they Key ------BEGIN RSA KEY------- and put it into a Notepad, then PuTTy Key Generator to make to .ppk.

Here is a great guide: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/log-into-a-linux-server-with-an-ssh-private-key-on-windows/

Comment: Thank you sam for the detailed answer,but I wanna to ssh the virtual machine from the controller node(Linux environment) and use python to do the job(without interaction with human)